# Nullable Int Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, ado.net

I am getting the error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Some of the Parent Id's can be null.  If I comment the ParentId it is successful, so I know it is that line.

```
var mModel = new MyModel
{
    //non nullable
    Id = int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString()),  
    //nullable
    ParentId = int.Parse(dr["ParentId"].ToString()),    <--- Throwing the error here
    //non nullable
    ProductService = dr["MyString"].ToString()
};
```

I have tried Convert.ToInt32(), and TryParse() and event a ToNullableInt extension Method, but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `int.Parse` on a value that will not parse correctly... it'll throw an exception.

If you're sure the value will be null or have a valid value, you could try this:

```
ParentId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr["ParentId"]))
               ? (int?)null
               : int.Parse(dr["ParentId"].ToString());
```

You may also want to look into [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which allows you to try parsing and take some alternative action if the parse fails:

```
int id;
if (Int32.TryParse(Convert.ToString(dr["ParentId"]), out id)
    ParentId = id;
else
    ParentId = 0;  // the parse failed
```

Incidentally, I like using `Convert.ToString()` over `.ToString()` in most cases, as the former converts `null` to an empty string, while the latter throws an exception. Just something to consider - doesn't help in this case, as `int.Parse("")` will throw an exception anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like calling to string on datareader, moreover, it has methods to get data of specific type

Pattern is

```
 if (!dr.IsDBNull(1)) s = dr.GetString(1)
```

Or for nullable int:

```
 if (!dr.IsDBNull(1)) i = dr.GetInt32(1)
```

Note: if you know column name and don't know ordinal or vise-a-versa, you can use `GetOrdinal` and 
`GetName` methods:

```
 var i = dr.GetOrdinal("ParentId")

 var name = dr.GetName(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for database null in the `dr["ParentId"]` and then convert to an `int` or assign null, like this:

```
ParentId = !dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("ParentId")) 
    ? dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("ParentId")) 
    : null;
```

---

> Note: The above code assumes that the `ParentId` variable is a nullable integer (`int?` or `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: `DataReader` has convinient `GetInt32` method, you don't need this.